# Upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10 to Kubuntu 11.04

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu

How can I upgrade from Ubuntu 10.10 to Kubuntu 11.04(beta 2)? Also, how much problems should I expect in the beta?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too difficult. Switching to Kubuntu is simply a matter of running `sudo tasksel kubuntu-desktop`. Then, you can do a normal upgrade. It shouldn't be a problem, though of course who knows what problems you'll encounter in the beta.

I don't agree with the advice to re-install. In my experience, there are only a few minor things that break during an upgrade, and re-installing and re-configuring takes a lot more time than fixing a few minor problems. I've upgraded though many releases without trouble. Admittedly, though, I always wait to upgrade until several weeks after the release to give time for bugs to get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If I go by previous upgrade attempts in older versions of Ubuntu, I always had more problems than saved time. Although it is time consuming to reinstall all applications and redo some settings and customizations, it saves me time in the long run for a couple of reasons:

- I do not have all the crapware that I installed since the last main installation
- I only have what I actually need and use, not everything else
- Some drivers do not go well through an upgrade process and you can loose wireless or sound or whatever else.
- When doing a re-install, it's also a good time to do a solid backup of all your files. When was your last backup ?

If everything is on a single partition, you may want to redistribute this on the next install. Like having /home mounted on its own partition, so you just re-connect it next time, as opposed to redo it all. Also, directories that can fill with log files, such as /var/messages or /var/logs could be on their own partition. If they fill in with errors, they will not crash your main disk.